# Pass Text Area Value From FXML To Controller

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I am new to fxml programming and am wanting to pass the value from a textbox created in my fxml to my controller.  i have wired up

```
fx:controller="sample.Controller"
```

so the controller can talk to the fxml - but this is the code I have, but I'm getting this error

```
<TextField fx:id="txtSearchTerm" layoutX="188.0" layoutY="56.0" />
```

```
@FXML TextField txtSearchTerm;

@FXML
private void QueryDB(ActionEvent event)
{
    //do stuff here\
    String selectedvalue = txtSearchTerm.getText();
}
```

What is the proper way to set this up?

[image: ja]

Comment: java naming conventions please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the type of `TextField` is from the `javafx.scene.control` namespace and not from the `java.awt` namespace